# Yahoo finance: download adjusted close prices of different stocks in one file

Tags: historical-data, yahoofinance

I am trying to download adjusted close prices of different stocks from yahoo finance. I used "Download to Spreadsheet" to download historical prices for each stock and then join these files into one. But it takes a lot of time. I wonder whether there exists a faster way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: this can be done very easily with custom programming, or with the bulkquotesxl plugin for excel if you don't want to program.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [pandas-datareader](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).
you will need to use python and write something like this:

```
# import package and notebook setting
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 999)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 999)
pd.set_option('precision', 4)
# load data
start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 9)
quotes = web.DataReader(["AAPL", "GOOGL", "TSLA"], 'yahoo', start, end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Best to download in R studio. use below code to download.

```
library(quantmod)

tickers = c("^NSEI","ITC.NS", "SBIN.NS", "COALINDIA.NS", "ICICIBANK.NS", "ADANIPORTS.NS", "ONGC.NS", "MOTHERSUMI.NS", "INFY.NS", "TCS.NS", "WIPRO.NS")

getSymbols(tickers, from = "2015-01-01", to = "2016-03-31")

prices.data <- merge(NSEI[,6], ITC.NS[,6], SBIN.NS[,6], COALINDIA.NS[,6], ICICIBANK.NS[,6], ADANIPORTS.NS[,6], ONGC.NS[,6], INFY.NS[,6], TCS.NS[,6], MOTHERSUMI.NS[,6], WIPRO.NS[,6])

head(prices.data)
```

you can use head(prices.data) to check the downloaded prices.